# Mysql array match

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I vave got a database PRODS, in that database I have got a table PRODUCTS, that table has a column PRODUCST_EXPORT, data in that columt is stored like this 1,3,5,8 or 1,16 (number range from 1 to 16) the user sends the array products[1,5,8,10] how i can build query that detects if there is match between that data user sent and data stored in PRODUCTS_EXPORT column

I need ot select rows if there is

1) at least one match 
2) more that one match 
3) full match

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: If you're storing comma seperated numbers in a single column AND you apparently save ranges as well as single seperated numbers, this is going to be close to impossible. You need to change the tables so that each number is stored in it's own row (probably by adding another table)

Comment: do you have to stick to that db schema or can you change it, because here it looks like `PRODUCT_EXPORTS` column should in fact be moved over a table so that you have no more `PRODUCT_EXPORT` column in `PRODUCTS` table, but you have a `PRODUCT_EXPORTS` table with `PRODUC_ID` and `EXPORT_ID` columns in that new table. Then you can do `select p.* from PRODUCTS p join PRODUCT_EXPORTS pe on p.ID = pe.PRODUCT_ID where pe.EXPORT_ID in (1, 2, 3)` where `(1, 2, 3)` is the list from the user.

Comment: No I don't have to stick to this db schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is never going be pretty.

In a situation like this you should set up a glue/linking table.
Meaning :

```
Table Products has : product_id(PK), etc.. 
Table Product_exports has : product_export_id(PK), product_id(FK), etc..
```

This way you can easily query with COUNT(), IN() and INNER JOIN to see if it has, exports and if it does if it has more then 1.